# ThickBox 3.1 issues, everything works, but pics aren't loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, gallery, thickbox

Anyone have any experience using the thickbox jquery plugin? I have it setup correctly, but for some reason it doesn't load my pictures. It will even go as far as to fade out and process the loading bar, but the picture itself doesn't load onto the screen. I haven't modified the code and I followed the instructions... not sure what the disconnect is here.

any ideas?

see the example @ http://www.dsi-usa.com/test/track.php click on one of the gallery links in the upper left and the loading bar just pops up and chills forever. any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an error in thickbox.js.  If you change `@rel` to `rel` on line 79, it works.

But, don't use thickbox.  [It's own web page](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/) has advised against it for over 2 years:

> While Thickbox had its day, it is not maintained any longer, so we recommend you use some alternatives.
>
> - [colorbox](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/)
> - [jQueryUI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)
> - [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/)
> - [DOM window](http://swip.codylindley.com/DOMWindowDemo.html)
> - [shadowbox.js](http://www.shadowbox-js.com/index.html)
>
> -*The Management. 9.30.2009 (and [Paul Irish](http://www.paulirish.com/))*

Comment: I appreciate it, I just needed to get something up quickly gonna probably switch over to fancybox over the weekend. Any suggestions???

Comment: @Brodie - I've added links to the jQuery recommended alternatives.  I don't have any personal recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the rel attribute from the anchor `(rel="product-gal")` it works:

```
<a class="thickbox" title="DSI's Modular Mac Keyboard" href="imgs/track-gallery/modmac-l.png">
<img src="imgs/track-gallery/modmac-t.png">
</a>
```